# Как исключить пользователей, у которых есть записи только с покупкой car?

Tags: sql

Есть такой SQL(из Django)-запрос:

```
SELECT "id", "name" 
FROM "polls_client" 
INNER JOIN "polls_purchases" ON ("id" = "client_id") 
WHERE "polls_purchases"."product" IN (car, bike)
```

Надо убрать пользователей, у которых есть записи о покупке car и нет bike. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT "polls_client"."id", "polls_client"."name" 
FROM "polls_client" 
INNER JOIN "polls_purchases" ON ("polls_client"."id" = "polls_purchases"."client_id") 
WHERE "polls_purchases"."product" IN (car, bike)
GROUP BY "polls_client"."id", "polls_client"."name" 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "polls_purchases"."product") = 1
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Забыл уточнить, что записи о покупках могут повторяться, т.е. покупок 'car' может быть больше одной. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: @Fyzzys Ну вот что мешает сперва попробовать, а? тогда и спрашивать бы не нужно было...

Comment: Мне очень жаль. Ошибся в формулировке задания, мне нужны пользователи, только которые купили bike, но не купили car

Comment: @Fyzzys Вот это не я писал: *Надо убрать пользователей, у которых есть записи о покупке и car и bike.* Т.е. тех, кто *купили только `bike`*, убирать не надо.